# Formatting appointment body

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to schedule a meeting automatically from Excel.
It is simple, unless you are trying to format the body text.
I made some research about GetInspector.
It looks like I have to copy the text from another place, but the commands I found are incorrect or not functional. Even trying to format it as RTF, but .RTFBody is not a property of the AppointmentItem object

Find my code:

```
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oMail As Object

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(1)

With oMail
    .Subject = ""
    .Location = ""
    '.Start =
    '.Duration =
    .body = " < not formattable text >"
    .display
End With

Set oApp = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

I once asked this question, and got an answer here (http://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/paste-formatted-text-vba/)

Try the following.  You will need to set a reference to the Word Object Model, and the formatted text should be stored in the clipboard, and note, you have to have the `.display` line before the `.body` line for there to be something to work with:

```
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oMail As Object

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(1)

With oMail
    .Subject = ""
    .Location = ""
    '.Start =
    '.Duration =
    ' .body = " < not formattable text >"
    .display
End With

Dim objItem As Object
Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Dim objSel As Word.Selection

Set objItem = oMail ' Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem
Set objInsp = objItem.GetInspector
Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
Set objWord = objDoc.Application
Set objSel = objWord.Selection

objSel.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
'objSel.PasteAndFormat (Word.WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

Set objItem = Nothing
Set objInsp = Nothing
Set objDoc = Nothing
Set objWord = Nothing
Set objSel = Nothing

Set oApp = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing
```

Hth