# format appointment body sometimes errors

Tags: vba, excel

I use the code described in this post a lot: [Formatting appointment body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665581/formatting-appointment-body/46015063#46015063)

It works most of the time, but sometimes has this error:

> 4605 This method or property is not available because the property is locked for editing

But then the next time it works fine. Any ideas how I can avoid this error?
Here is some of my code:

```
Set objItem = olAppt ' Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem
Set objInsp = objItem.GetInspector
Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
Set objWord = objDoc.Application
Set objSel = objWord.Selection
objSel.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)'Code errors here
```

Comment: can you please show us your code and also mention on which line you are getting this error?

Comment: maybe this link will help [How to edit existing MailItem using WordEditor in Outlook VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510335/how-to-edit-existing-mailitem-using-wordeditor-in-outlook-vba)